# When C#8 is released, on what frameworks will it run on?

Tags: c#-8.0

When C# 8 is released, will it be targeting .NET Core 3.x only or will it be able to target existing frameworks too? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 1):

The answers to this question can only be links to the official announcements and blog posts. From Mads Torgersen's [Building C# 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/building-c-8-0/)

> **Platform dependencies**
>
> Many of the C# 8.0 language features have platform dependencies. Async streams, indexers and ranges all rely on new framework types that will be part of .NET Standard 2.1. As Immo describes in his post [Announcing .NET Standard 2.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/), .NET Core 3.0 as well as Xamarin, Unity and Mono will all implement .NET Standard 2.1, but *.NET Framework 4.8 will not.* This means that the types required to use **these features won’t be available on .NET Framework 4.8.** Likewise, default interface member implementations rely on new runtime enhancements, and we will not make those in the .NET Runtime 4.8 either.
>
> For this reason, using C# 8.0 **is only supported on platforms that implement .NET Standard 2.1.**

We'll get more information at Build 2019. I wouldn't be surprised to hear there's a migration path for older code, especially now that .NET Core 3.0 supports WPF and Windows Forms